Azure Managed Identity Authentication Fails in Production for Next.js App with Sequelize and Tedious
I'm deploying a Next.js application to Azure App Service and using Sequelize as my ORM. For authentication, I'm utilizing Azure Managed Identity with the Tedious library to connect to an SQL Server. While everything works perfectly in development, I encounter a "login failed" error in production.
I'm using the following configuration for Tedious:
const options: SequelizeOptions = {
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: 1433,
  dialect: "mssql",
  logging: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? console.log : false,
  dialectModule: tedious,
  dialectOptions: {
    authentication: {
      type: "azure-active-directory-default",
      options: {
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID, // user - assigned 
        encypt: true,
      },
    },
  },
};

I've tried both system-assigned and user-assigned identities. For the user-assigned identity, I have provide the client id.
What could be causing the managed identity authentication to fail in production while it works in development?
Are there any additional configurations needed for managed identity in an Azure App Service production environment?
Resources : tedious, Microsoft passwordless connections with Azure SQL Database Link

Managed Identity does not work locally as mentioned in the MS Document. If you are using DefaultAzureCredential it uses Azure CLI or Other credentials to authenticate the request.

you need assign the Managed Identity/ User Assigned Identity db_datareder, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin role in your database to allow access to the db.

this is already done.

Can you share the raw error content

{
"mssg": {
"name": "SequelizeAccessDeniedError",
"parent": {
"code": "ELOGIN"
},
"original": {
"code": "ELOGIN"
}
}
} Getting Error in prod while it's working fine in dev

Is the dev also deployed on Azure?

No locally I checked

Have you added your user assigned identity in you Azure web app service?

I have tried with both managed and user identity

In DefaultAzureCredential and ManagedIdentityCredential, these can be provided as environment variables -
at async u._connect
"AZURE_TENANT_ID",
at async
"AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
parent: AggregateError
"AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE". See the troubleshooting guide for more information: https://aka.ms/azsdk/js/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot
CredentialUnavailableError: ManagedIdentityCredential: Authentication failed. Message ManagedIdentityCredential - No MSI credential available

DefaultAzureCredential uses multiple methods which include Environent variables, workload, managed identiy, azurecCLI, intractive browser.  check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity#:~:text=DefaultAzureCredential%20is%20intended%20to%20simplify%20getting%20started%20with%20the%20SDK%20by%20handling%20common%20scenarios%20with%20reasonable%20default%20behaviors.%20Developers%20who%20want%20more%20control%20or%20whose%20scenario%20isn%27t%20served%20by%20the%20default%20settings%20should%20use%20other%20credential%20types.

I have tried adding the tenant and client id of user assigned managed identity in the env but still not working

I have tried this one also.

type: "azure-active-directory-access-token", It's also working fine in dev but not in production.

Testing EnvironmentCredential...
EnvironmentCredential failed:
Testing ManagedIdentityCredential...
ManagedIdentityCredential failed:
Testing AzureCliCredential...
AzureCliCredential failed:
Testing DefaultAzureCredential...
DefaultAzureCredential succeeded.

is it working fine now?

no, In local it's using defaultazurecredential for authentiction

I tried the sequelize code in The Expressjs it is working fine in production and devlopment. but error it is throwing error in Nextjs. I think issue is related to the next framework in production.

I have used the DefaultAzureCredential for azure key vault aswell. It was working fine. May be issue with next

Yes I think so. instead of tedious try mssql with sequelize.

if possible try using next as fontend only and express as backend

tedious is required. https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/databases/mssql/

in dialectModule; Mssql

As I mentioned in comment code is working fine in Expressjs but not in Nextjs.
It would be much better to use express as backend
Add the User Assigned Identity in Azure Web App service.

Below express code i used for my web app
import express from 'express';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import tedious from 'tedious';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

async function get_data(){
  const options = {
    database: 'testswldb',
    host: 'testsqlbdserver.database.windows.net',
    port: 1433,
    dialect: "mssql",
    dialectModule: tedious,
    dialectOptions: {
      authentication: {
        type: "azure-active-directory-default",
        options: {
          clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', // user-assigned client id
          encrypt: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(options)
  try{
    await sequelize.authenticate()
    return 'Connection has been established successfully.';
  }
  catch(err) {
    return `Unable to connect to the database: ${err}`;
  };
}


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send("weclome to express app")
})

app.get('/dbdata', async(req,res) => {
  res.send(await get_data())
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

OUTPUT:


I have tried this one too but not working.  Can you tell me step by step what you did. I have deployed the express app correctly. assigned identity as well, system + user. I think issue is with sql server

@JagdishPadeliya is it working locally? or is it not working for you in both?

yeah working fine locally.

When I used the other method for authentication (azure-active-directory-access-token), I am able to see the token in the azure log.

if possible can you share your repo? @JagdishPadeliya

upon investigating the logs got to know that it's not using the client id we wants. I can't share the repo.

Okay.  are you providing the correct client id in  code?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have given the DBcontributor role as well as owner but still no luck

https://imgur.com/30OtGtD

https://imgur.com/Pvs8w2W

I would suggest trying mssql package instead of sequelize
